# Render 2d gaussian - take gradient with respect to the mean

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision

I need to render a 2d gaussian and still be able to differentiate with respect to the 2d mean, which has type float. The standard deviation of the gaussian can be constant. Same for the size of the matrix that is generated.

Any idea how to do this in tensorflow?

**CLARIFICATION:**

I need a function draw2dGaussian(mean2d) which returns a 2d matrix M. The matrix M will show a discretized 2d gaussian centered at the location mean2d. Note that mean2d is a pair of 2 floats. The matrix M will be 0 at the points far enough from the mean2d.

The requirement of this function draw2dGaussian is that it has to be differentiable with respect to mean2d.

I think openDR http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/black/papers/OpenDR.pdf might be able to offer such a function, but I was wondering if somebody had a simpler solution.

Comment: i tried to clarify it, please let me know if there's more doubt

Comment: Yes, that makes it a lot clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the reparametrization trick. For a one-dimensional gaussian, N(mean, var) can be written as mean + sqrt(var) * N(0, 1). A similar construction applies to 2d gaussians but with a covariance matrix instead of a constant variance.